# Second derivative of $\mbox {tr}(A^n V)$

Tags: matrices, derivatives, matrix-calculus, trace, scalar-fields

I have a problem with derivative of trace of a matrix. Given (symmetric) matrix $A, E$ and $V$, I want to obtain second-order Taylor expansion of $f(A) : = {\tt {tr}}(A^n V)$ near $E$ such that
$$
f(A + E) \approx f(A) + \text{vec}(E)^\top \nabla_A f(A) + \frac12 \text{vec}(E)^\top \left(\nabla_A^2 f(A)\right)\text{vec}(E)
$$

First derivative is follows:
$$
%\frac{\partial {\tt tr}(A^n V)}{\partial A} 
\nabla_A f(A) = \nabla_A {\tt tr}(A^n V) = \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} A^{j} V A^{n-j-1}
$$

However, for the second derivative, it is hard to obtain closed form to me. 
Any guidance will be helpful.
Many thanks!

Comment: Hint: $vec(AV + VA) = (vec V \otimes vec I) vec A + (vec I \otimes vec V) vec A$.

Comment: @ user1497614 , the @ Rodrigo de Azevedo 's answer is a good one; you can (you must) accept it.

Answer (score 0):

$$(\mathrm X + h \mathrm M)^n = \mathrm X^n + h \left( \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} \mathrm X^k \mathrm M \mathrm X^{n-1-k} \right) + h^2 \left(\sum_{\begin{array}{c} k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = n-2\\ k_1, k_2, k_3 \geq 0\end{array}} \mathrm X^{k_1} \mathrm M \mathrm X^{k_2} \mathrm M \mathrm X^{k_3} \right) + O (h^3)$$

Hence, the **2nd order** term of $\mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm A (\mathrm X + h \mathrm M)^n \right)$ is

$$h^2 \sum_{\begin{array}{c} k_1 + k_2 + k_3 = n-2\\ k_1, k_2, k_3 \geq 0\end{array}} \mbox{tr} \left( \mathrm A \mathrm X^{k_1} \mathrm M \mathrm X^{k_2} \mathrm M \mathrm X^{k_3} \right)$$